# zend2 redirected value not getting in the another action of the same controller

Tags: zend-framework2

I am passing through this

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('ModuleName',array('controller'=>$controllerName,'action' => $actionName,'params' =>$params));
```

param values is not getting is request parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the controller `redirect` plugin is not responsable for redirecting to another module. but you can redirect to a route that points in the configuration to another module/controller.

`$this->redirect('route_name', $params, $options)`

make sure that the redirect route is configured to receive your params.

if you forward to current request to a other controller action in the same module use the `forward` controller plugin.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html